# Unresolved symbol error

Tags: c++, header-files, extern, unresolved-external, compilationunit

I'm working through exercises from Programming Principles and Practice using Visual Studio 2012. When trying to compile the source code below I'm getting a linker error:

> unresolved symbol int foo.

I don't understand why the symbol is unresolved.

#### my.h

```
extern int foo;
void print_foo();
void print(int);
```

#### my.cpp

```
#include "my.h"
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"

void print_foo()
{
    cout<<foo<<'\n';
}

void print(int i)
{
    cout<<i<<'\n';
}
```

#### use.cpp

```
#include "my.h"

int main(){
    int foo = 7;

    print_foo();
    print(99);
}
```

Comment: Format your code properly please!

Comment: You never defined a `foo` in the global namespace. `extern int foo;` is only a declaration, not a definition. The only definition of `foo` is a local variable in `main()`.

Comment: does it matter which of the files the global definition for foo is?

Comment: Yes, and No.  No; you could define it in either source file (not the header) and the code would link.  Yes; you should define it in `my.cpp` because it is part of the interface provided by the `my.h` and `my.cpp` files.  If you have 6 programs using the `my` package, you'd not want the each of those programs to have to define the global `foo`.

Comment: T.C. thanks a lot the info provided was very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
extern int foo;
```

This is a *declaration*. It tells the compiler "there's going to be an variable called `foo` of type `int` in the global namespace defined somewhere".

```
int main(){    
    int foo = 7;
    // ...
}
```

This defines a local variable `foo` of type `int` inside the function `main()` and initializes it to 7. This local variable is not visible outside of `main()`.

What you didn't do is actually *define* `foo` in the global namespace. To do that, add this line to *exactly one* of either `my.cpp` or `use.cpp`, after the includes:

```
int foo;
```

This defines a variable called `foo` of type `int` in the global namespace. (As an object of static storage duration, `foo` is initialized to zero by default, though you can also provide a different initializer if you want.) The linker should then be able to resolve the reference to the global `foo` that's in `print_foo()` when you link the object files together.

It is very important that you only *define* `foo` once, though you can *declare* it as many times as you want. Doing otherwise violates the One Definition Rule and results in a linker error if you are lucky, and undefined behavior if you are not.

Answer (score 2):

This statement

```
extern int foo;
```

is a declaration of name foo. It is not the definition of foo.

You have to initialize this variable that it would be a definition. For example

```
extern int foo = 0;
```

Though I do not see a sense in your code.

Maybe you meant the following. I suppose that the variable defined in the module because I do not see a sense of using the header if there is only one module.

```
/* my.cpp */

#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"

extern int foo = 0;
void print_foo();
void print(int);

void print_foo()
{
    cout<<foo<<'\n';
}

void print(int i)
{
    cout<<i<<'\n';
}

int main(){

    extern int foo;
    foo = 7;

    //...
```

If you want to use header then the code could look as

```
/* my.h */

extern int foo;
void print_foo();
void print(int);

/* my.cpp */

#include "my.h"
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"


int foo;

void print_foo()
{
    cout<<foo<<'\n';
}

void print(int i)
{
    cout<<i<<'\n';
}

/* use.cpp */

#include "my.h"

int main(){

    extern int foo;
    foo = 7;

    print_foo();
    print(99);
}
```

Comment: You don't have to initialize a variable to make it a definition. `extern` means 'defined elsewhere'. A definition would be just `int foo;`.

Comment: And anyway, putting the definition for non-inline functions or for variable into headers is a bad idea.

Comment: There are several ways to define the variable.  One is the technique shown by Vlad (`extern int foo = 0;`); another is to omit the `extern`, leaving `int foo = 0;`, while yet a third would omit both `extern` and the initializer (`int foo;` at file scope).  Of course, the variable definition must not be in the header because if it is put in the header, only one file per program can include the header, which makes the header pointless in the first place.

Comment: @Inspired You said a stupidy. The linker issued the error that the variable is undefined. So you have to define it.

Comment: `extern int foo;` is needless in `main()'. Header file `my.h` provides info about global variable `foo`.

Comment: @Dakorn I provided two code examples. The both code examples are correct. What code example are you speaking about?